# how to redirect stdin or block keyboard inputs?

Tags: bash

I'm printing an progress bar in bash but it "breaks" when the user hit any key. I would like to either redirect stdin or block the keyboard input but I haven't been able to do it. This is my code (a small extract from the whole code)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while [[ true ]]; do
echo -n "#" && 0> /dev/null
sleep 1
done
```

any help will be very appreciate it :-)

Comment: Don't worry about it. Every program I've used that has a progress bar "breaks" in the same way. It's not something you should try to prevent; it's the nature of terminal programs.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, I know it's not a big deal and I should focus on other part of my script, but let's say I'm a littler perfectionist and I would like to fix it :-p

Comment: It's not broken, so there's nothing to fix. You're wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Ansgar is correct.  You can mess around with redirecting stdin, but I'm not sure this will help, per your definition, your scripting effort at all. Here are some attempts going in the direction you seem to think is correct:

retty:

```
http://pasky.or.cz/dev/retty/
```

reptyr:

```
http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/
```

Play with these for a while, then see why Ansgar has the right of it, IMO.  Or maybe you might think this is okay.